# Is it safe to create invisible TComponent derived class for handling specific part of a big Form?

Tags: c++, builder, vcl

There are cases when some part of a big form should be reusable in other form(s).
In this case the recommended way is to create new component derived from one of the existing VCL classes.
But it takes more time to prepare it to use in visual designer.
A simpler solution would be to use intermediate step in which affected group of elements are handled by newly created aggregator class, which acts as a controller. Controller class doesn't need to own these elements but may need to provide its own methods for handling click events.

Below is code example that illustrates described approach.
**The question** is how safe it is? **Could it
crash** application while form manages its components in runtime?

```
class MyController
{
public:
    // for initialization:
    TPanel *pnl;
    TCheckBox *cb1;
    TCheckBox *cb2;
    TCheckBox *cb3;
    TEdit inpt;

    void SetAdditionalParameters(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        // ... more code (source.cpp) ... //
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }

    // public interface: 
    void DoAction1(int param);
    void DoAction2(int param);
    void DoAction3(int param);

private:
    int a, b, c;

    // internal functions
    void InternalFunc();

    // internal event handlers 
    void __fastcall InternaOnClick(TObject *Sender);
};

class MyBigForm : public Form
{
    __published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TImage *imgBack;
    // ... more members ...// 
    // Elements to be controlled below:
    TPanel *pnl;
    TCheckBox *cb1;
    TCheckBox *cb2;
    TCheckBox *cb3;
    TEdit inpt;
    // end elements to be controlled

public:
    __fastcall MyBigForm(TComponent* Owner);
    virtual __fastcall ~MyBigForm(void);

    bool __fastcall Init()
    {
        // ... more code ... // 
        subView.pnl = pnl;
        subView.cb1 = cb1;
        subView.cb2 = cb2;
        subView.cb3 = cb3;
        subView.inpt = inpt;
        subView.SetAdditionalParameters(1, 2, 3);
        // don't care about delegated elements (use MyController interface)
    }

private:
    MyController subView;
};
```

**Update**
As it was pointed out in the comment below, there is a better approach - by using TFrame instead.

I am new to VCL library and I admit that my approach can lead to crash if form components might be recreated at runtime by VCL.
So I would rephrase original question into:
Can VCL recreate components at runtime, which were added to a form manually from IDE?

Comment: An easier solution is to use a `TFrame` instead. You can design it visually inside the IDE just like a `TForm` at design-time, put whatever controls and event handlers in it as needed, and then create and position instances of the `TFrame` on your `TForm`s as needed. No controller required.

Comment: This matches exactly the idea of having same functionality defined in one place. Thank you! It looks as right and quick approach.